# elasticSearch - SUM aggregation returns double instead of long

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am doing a multiple aggregation on a LONG field (eventSize).

Is there any way to request another format without losing the precision in the output of the sum aggregation?

Below are the parts of the request used and response I got.

Query:

```
"aggs": {
        "eventTermsAgg": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "eventType"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "splitPerDayAgg": {
                    "date_histogram": {
                        "field": "date",
                        "fixed_interval": "1d",
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "eventSizeAgg": {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "eventSize",
                                "format": "##.00"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Response:

```
"key": "112233",
     "doc_count": 123,
         "splitPerDayAgg": {
             "buckets": [
             {
                 "key_as_string": "2022-12-15",
                 "key": 123456789,
                 "doc_count": 3456,
                 "eventSizeAgg": {
                 "value": 1.01724077E8,
                 "value_as_string": "101724077.00"
             }
     }
```

I tried using the "format": "##.00" in the SUM aggs parameters, but it only returns the same value as string, losing the precision of the actual sum.

Comment: sum aggregation calculate exact value of sum. It's not like a cardinality aggs. what do you mean by `losing the precision?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the response you shared, I don't see any precision lost: the original value is expressed in the E-notation `1.01724077E8`, which corresponds to the `101724077.00` value reported in the `value_as_string` field.

However, I'm not sure why you want to show decimals in a sum of LONG values.

Comment: my mistake. I initially started with aggregating float values and got lost in translation. For long value works fine if I use “value_as_string”. Thanks for pointing that out!